# Django and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, django

I've got some boolean fields on a model inside of my app. They default to false and I want to write a function that toggles them between true and false.

Then on my template, I want that function to operate based on a checkbox. Then allow the checkbox to show checked if true and un checked if false.

I'm just not sure should I be doing this with a URL and a view or is this a form?

Here's what I've got so far:

models.py

```
class CarrierCompany(models.Model):
    rgn = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    van = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    power_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    step_deck = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    flatbed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reefer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hotshot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    specialized = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def rgn_equipment(self):
        if self.rgn == False:
            self.rgn = True
        else:
            self.rgn = False
        self.save()
```

views.py

```
def rgn_equipment_toggle(request, pk):
    carrier_company = get_object_or_404(CarrierCompany, pk=pk)
    carrier_company.rgn_equipment()
    return redirect('accounts:carrier_company_detail', pk=pk)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'rgn_equipment_toggle/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', rgn_equipment_toggle, name='rgn_equipment_toggle'),
]
```

template

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel tile fixed_height_235">
      <div class="x_title">
        <h3>Equipment Type
          <input type="checkbox" data-target="{% url 'accounts:rgn_equipment_toggle' pk=carriercompany.pk %}" />

          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="x_content">
        {{ carriercompany.rgn }}
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
            var item = $(this);
            if (item.is(":checked")) {
              window.location.href = item.data("target")
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can get this to work perfectly with a button so that is an option. I'm just not sure how to accomplish this with a checkbox.  I'm assuming I need to operate and show the checkbox checked/not checked with Jquery so I also started with some code there but I'm extremely new to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple hours off and I solved this. silly me. I'm not sure if this is the best way because it includes logic inside of the template but this is how I solved it for now.

```
{% if carriercompany.rgn == True %}
   <input type="checkbox" data-target="{% url 'accounts:rgn_equipment_toggle' pk=carriercompany.pk %}" checked />
{% else %}
   <input type="checkbox" data-target="{% url 'accounts:rgn_equipment_toggle' pk=carriercompany.pk %}" />
{% endif %}
```

And the same script above that allows you to toggle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
         var item = $(this);
         if (item.is(":checked")) {
         window.location.href = item.data("target")
         }else {
          window.location.href = item.data("target")
        }
       });
   });
</script>
```